# Why may club Berkeley cardinals not be Berkeley?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

["Large Cardinals beyond Choice"](https://events.math.unipd.it/aila2017/sites/default/files/BAGARIA.pdf) makes the following definitions:

> $\delta$ is a Berkeley cardinal if for every transitive set $M$ such that $\delta \in m$ and every $\eta \lt \delta$ there exists $j \in \mathcal{E} (M)$ with $\eta \lt crit(j) \lt \delta$.

> $\delta$ is a club Berkeley cardinal if $\delta$ is regular and for all clubs $C \subseteq \delta$ and all transitive sets $M$ with $\delta \in M$ there exists $j \in \mathcal{E}$ with $crit(j) \in c$.

The differences that I can see is that for Berkeley cardinals, the critical points are required to be unbounded in $\delta$ while for club Berkeley cardinals there must be critical points in every club, and that club Berkeley cardinals must be regular. Since the ordinals between $\eta$ and $\delta$, for any $\eta \lt \delta$, constitute a club, **it appears that club Berkeley cardinals are Berkeley**. However, the diagram in the slides lists no implication from club Berkeley cardinals to Berkeley. **What am I missing?**

Comment: As you note, club Berkeleys are always Berkeley. Probably the arrows are supposed to be "strict" implications, and maybe it's unknown whether e.g., ZF + a club Berkeley proves the consistency of ZF plus a Berkeley.